# Rails / Prototype - Modalbox Dialog Centering Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototype, modal-dialog, centering

I have an issue with the Prototype Modalbox Dialog not fully displaying in the user's browser, depending upon the user's screen resolution.  For example, part of the content in the Modalbox is cut off by the browser viewport, and there's no way for the user to view it.

I believe it has something to do with the sequence of the content and Modalbox being loaded. For example, the Modalbox Dialog is generated, THEN the content is loaded -- this ultimately results in the Dialog not being centered in the user's browser viewport.

I am wondering if anyone else has ran into this issue?  If so, what are you programmatically doing to make sure that the Dialog display optimally?

Comment: Can you make sure it is really caused by the sequence of content and modalbox being loaded? Maybe you can delay the modalbox loading after some seconds (long enough until the content finish loading), and see the result.

Comment: Can you post a link to the Modalbox library? Is it this one? http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/ Also a link to your project would help.

Comment: Hi, which version of Prototype are you using? I remember having similar problem with one of the latest beta 1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember having this issue. Usually it happens when ModalBox doesn't know the width/height of the content that it's loading. These steps help (no need to apply all of them, try and see what works best for you):

1) Wrap the content that will be shown in ModalBox in a DIV and set the height/width CSS properties for it.

2) Make sure that if there are images in the ModalBox content, that they have the width height also set.

3) Preload the content before you even display the ModalBox.

4) Use ModalBox callbacks (onShow if I remember correctly), and call the function to recenter it.